# how to use combineLatest/zip but only react to emits of second observable and ignore emits from first observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

So I have this property initialization:

```
this.currentMapObject$ = zip(this.mapObjects$, this.currentMapObjectsIndex$,
      (mapObjects, index) => mapObjects[index]);
```

I only want to emit this.currentMapObject$ if this.currentMapObjectsIndex$ emits but not if this.mapObjects$ emits.

As far as I know now this.currentMapObject$ will emit even if a single property of an item of this.mapObjects$ changes. I want to ignore all changes to this.mapObjects$ and only take its current value, but I DO want to react to this.currentMapObjectsIndex$ changes

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at withLatestFrom:

> Combines the source Observable with other Observables to create an Observable whose values are calculated from the latest values of each, only when the source emits.

https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/withLatestFrom

As per @BizzyBob suggestion:

```
this.currentMapObject$ = this.currentMapObjectsIndex$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.mapObjects$),
  map(([index, mapObjects]) => {
    // ...
  }
)
```

Comment: `this.currentMapObject$ = this.currentMapObjectsIndex$.pipe(withLatestFrom(this.mapObjects$), map(([index, mapObjects]) => mapObjects[index])))`